# Недавно удалённые?

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, 10k-tools

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last30days

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде вполне себе живут и здравствуют:

[Заходы на сайт с временем 00:00:00](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924615/15479)

[Заполнение бд на mysql с помощью CSV файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/924275/15479)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы не заметили небольшую деталь: вы смотрите список удаленных на мете, а вопросы "живут и здравствуют" на основном сайте. С меты они [действительно удалены](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8439/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-000000?noredirect=1)